# Jenkins: How to checkout only new files and modified files when creating new branch

Tags: git, jenkins

I am using Multibranch pipeline in Jenkins. I've some pretty large project - When creating a new branch, I'd like the git plugin to only checkout new files or changed files compared to a branch

Is there a way to do that? I know once the branch exist, as long as I don't clean the workspace, it will just checkout new files and updated one, but what about new branches?

Comment: You can try sparse checkout https://naiveskill.com/jenkins-sparse-checkout/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have two branches, 'old-branch' and 'new-branch', both of which are synced with the remote.

```bash
git checkout old-branch
# Create a local branch called "new-branch"
# WARNING! Could blow away commits if you added them to to an existing local branch called "new-branch"
git switch -C new-branch 
# Set the branch's HEAD without doing a checkout
git reset --soft origin/new-branch
# Un-stage staged changes
git reset
```

The repo's working copy of its files will be what they were before we started. Run `git status` to see differences.

- If a new file was added to `new-branch` it'll show up as `deleted`.
- If a file was removed in `new-branch`, it'll show up as untracked.
- If a file was modified, it'll show up as modified.

If you then run:

```bash
git checkout .
```

This will undo all the modifications, and restore all the "deleted" (according to git) files, but importantly **will not remove the untracked files**. This accomplishes what your original question states.